# XPages Tag cloud

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, tag-cloud

I would to show the tagcloud value individually in each line. Like a list

value1

value2

value3
...
...
..

This is my code. Everytime I choose a value from the list, the display list also got filtered.

This code work in XPNIC without a problem. In the browser I am having the problem as stated above.

```
<xp:section id="section2" header="Web" type="wide">
    <xp:panel>
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView var="view2" viewName="TagCloudActiveCategories" expandLevel="1">
            </xp:dominoView>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:repeat id="repeat2" rows="30" value="#{view2}" indexVar="indexVar" var="rowData">
            <xe:list id="list2" styleClass="lotusList">
                <xp:link escape="true" id="link1" value="/allDocumentsByTag.xsp">
                    <xp:this.text><![CDATA[# {javascript:rowData.getColumnValues()[0];}]]></xp:this.text>
                    <xp:this.parameters>
                        <xp:parameter name="categoryFilter">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[# {javascript:getComponent("link1").getText();}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:parameter>
                    </xp:this.parameters>
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh"></xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:link>
            </xe:list>
        </xp:repeat>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:section>
```

Any help is very welcome. Thank you in advance.
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: "as stated above"... Sorry, but what is your problem?

Comment: Hi Sven, thank you for asking.  I have the code above and it works in XPiNC well no issues. I have this LIST  like a (tag cloud). When I take this app into the browser, and choose any entry from the LIST (for view filtering) the LIST also got updated or filtered (i.e. I have 4 items on the list, when I choose any item from the list the list get update and display only the pick item).

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? I still don't get it...

Comment: Hi Sven, Thank for the interest once again. I have attached screenshot above and update also my code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can see you are using URL parameters to filter your view. This parameter is used by *EVERY* view datasource on your XPage, even the datasource of your tag cloud.

Add the property *ignoreRequestParams=true* to your tag cloud view, this should solve the problem.

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view2" viewName="TagCloudActiveCategories" expandLevel="1" ignoreRequestParams="true">
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>
```